# Springloops "Commit failed" with status 165002

Tags: svn, cornerstone, springloops

This just popped up today without any changes to our configurations. The description for the error (redacted) is "Failed to start '/var/data/backend/repositories/svn/a/b/c/d/e/accountname/projectname/hooks/start-commit' - Status : 165002"

The access log at Springloops only shows successful reads, but no errors with commits (we use Cornerstone SVN). Has anyone had similar issues... and if so, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, Springloops provides hosted Subversion repositories. Therefore, I would recommend that you contact its support for assistance. I think that the problem is on their side and you can't solve it yourself.

Besides contacting their support, try committing using the `svn` command line client. You should see full wording of the error message that will give you additional hints. It also makes sense to [check the logs on server side](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.extra.logging) if possible.

The problem is with the [`start-commit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.reposhooks.start-commit.html) hook script configured in the repository. When the `start-commit` exits with an error - no commit is made to the repository. The server cannot start the hook by some reason.